# Subtracting one row of data from another in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, join, subtraction

I've been stumped with some SQL where I've got several rows of data, and I want to subtract a row from the previous row and have it repeat all the way down.

So here is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id,
  length
)
```

```
INSERT INTO foo (id,length) VALUES(1,1090)
INSERT INTO foo (id,length) VALUES(2,888)
INSERT INTO foo (id,length) VALUES(3,545)
INSERT INTO foo (id,length) VALUES(4,434)
INSERT INTO foo (id,length) VALUES(5,45)
```

I want the results to show a third column called difference which is one row subtracting from the one below with the final row subtracting from zero.

```
+------+------------------------+
| id   |length |  difference  |
+------+------------------------+
|    1 | 1090  |  202         |
|    2 |  888  |  343         |
|    3 |  545  |  111         |
|    4 |  434  |  389         |
|    5 |   45  |   45         |
```

I've tried a self join but I'm not exactly sure how to limit the results instead of having it cycle through itself.  I can't depend that the id value will be sequential for a given result set so I'm not using that value.  I could extend the schema to include some kind of sequential value.

This is what I've tried:

```
SELECT id, f.length, f2.length, (f.length - f2.length) AS difference
FROM foo f, foo f2
```

Thank you for the assist.

Comment: This is MySQL.  Forgive me for not mentioning earlier.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This might help you (somewhat).

```
select a.id, a.length, 
coalesce(a.length - 
    (select b.length from foo b where b.id = a.id + 1), a.length) as diff
from foo a
```

Comment: Use of COALESCE will fix the last row having NULL

Comment: he wants zero to be subtracted from last row so difference column should have 45 but your script is giving 0

Comment: I hope that is SQL server & not mysql :p

Comment: I was racking my brain for a solution to an issue very close to this one.  This was a fantastic answer!

Comment: This solution works but still one thing is that the performance of using sub queries is not very good.  You can do the same thing by using an inner join which would also eliminate the null values

Answer (score 7):

Yipee!!! this does the trick:

```
SELECT  f.id, f.length, 
    (f.length - ISNULL(f2.length,0)) AS diff
FROM foo f
LEFT OUTER JOIN foo f2
ON  f2.id = (f.id +1)
```

Please check for other cases also, it is working for the values you posted!
Note this is for SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 3):

So they are just ordered largest to smallest?

```
SELECT f.id, f.length, (f.length - ISNULL(t.length, 0)) AS difference
FROM foo AS f
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT f1.id
        ,MAX(f2.length) as length
    FROM foo AS f1
    INNER JOIN foo AS f2
        ON f1.length > f2.length
    GROUP BY f1.id
) AS t -- this is the triangle
    ON t.id = f.id
```

You can use `COALESCE` (or `IFNULL`) instead of `ISNULL` for MySQL.

Comment: @Cade: +1 
One more way to do the same thing. I hope the OP wants solution in SQL Server ;)

Comment: This is the only solution so far which is independent of id.  The only thing in MySQL ISNULL -> COALESCE.

Comment: Sure, I made the assumption that next row's id = current row's id + 1

Comment: You need to use the AS length I had added on my last update.  I tested on MySQL 5.1 and it works.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

```
SELECT T2.ID, T2.[Length], T2.[Length]-T1.[Length] AS 'Difference'
FROM Foo AS T1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN Foo AS T2 ON ( T1.ID = (T2.ID-1) )
ORDER BY T1.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

edit: fixed when re-read Q (misunderstood)

```
SELECT f.id, 
       f2.id, 
       f.length, 
       f2.length, 
       (f.length -f2.length) AS difference
FROM foo f, 
     foo f2 
where f2.id = f.id+1
```

id was ambiguous

edit: note: tested in mysql 5.0

Answer (score 1):

```
Select f1.id, f1.seqnum, f2.seqnum, f1.length, f2.length, f1.length-f2.length 

From (

Select Id, length, row_number(order by length) 'seqnum'
From
foo

) f1

Inner join (

Select 
Id, length, row_number(order by length) 'seqnum' from foo union select 0, 0, 0

) f2 

On f1.seqnum = f2.seqnum + 1

Order by f1.length desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it was interesting to look at your solutions.
I find it strange that such a normal-life problem is so complicated in SQL.
As I need the values in a report only, I chose a completely different solution.
I'm running Ruby on Rails as the front end of my sqlite3 database, and just did the subtraction in the view like this:

In your ruby controller, there is a object variable @foo that holds the rows returned by your query.

In the view, just do

```
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>length</th>
    <th>difference</th>
  </tr>

<% for i in 0..@foo.length-1 do %>
  <tr>
    <td><%=h @foo[i].id %></td>
    <td><%=h @foo[i].length %></td>
    <td><% if (i==@foo.length-1) then %>
        <%=  @foo[i].length %>
      <% else %>
        <%= @foo[i+1].length.to_i - @foo[i].length.to_i %>
      <% end %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Seems to be more robust than the SQL solutions.